# Automapper many-to-many stackoverflowexception

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm getting a stack overflow for the following mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent, ParentViewModel>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Children, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Children.ConvertToChildrenViewModel()));

Mapper.CreateMap<Children, ChildrenViewModel>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Parents, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Parents.ConvertToParentViewModel()));
```

I understand why this is happening, clearly an infinite loop here. How am I supposed to get this to work in automapper? I need parents to know about their children and their children to know about their parents. Would I have to create another `ViewModel` for `Children.Parents` that doesn't contain the `Parents.Children` property?

Extension methods example, similarly for children:

```
public static IList<ParentViewModel> ConvertToParentViewModel(this IEnumerable<Parent> parents)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<IList<ParentViewModel>>(parents);
        }
```

Comment: What methods `ConvertToChildrenViewModel` and `ConvertToParentViewModel` actually do? Please show the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoMapper does keep track of what's mapped, but only in the context of a single Map call, not multiple external calls to Mapper.Map.

You shouldn't need the ForMember piece on either mapping configuration. If you remove that, AutoMapper will traverse the parent/child relationships and keep track of what has already been mapped.

Comment: Thanks again Jimmy for the help!

Answer (score 8):

There's a `MaxDepth` setting you can use for recursive mappings.  I've never used it before, but it may help you out.  You set it on the type mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(...).MaxDepth(5)
```

Comment: Looks like I don't need the ForMember. Not sure why we had that in there for the collections but it's working now without the ForMember.